# ¿Por qué el texto me sale en 2 filas y 2 columnas en lugar de 1 fila con 4 columnas?

Tags: html, css, tablas

Tengo el código HTML

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
      /* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
      .column {
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
        padding: 5px;
      }
      /* Clear floats after the columns */
      .row:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
      }
      .center {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 50%;
      }
      .t1{
       color:#624662;
       text-align: center;
       font-size: 14px;
      }
      .t2{
       color:#fc8e04;
       text-align: center;
       font-size: 35px;
      }
      img{
        horizontal-align: middle;
     }
        
      /* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 600px wide, make the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   
  </head>
  <body>
    <br>
       <div class="row">
         <div class="column">
           <div style="text-align: center">
          <img src="URL" class="middle" width="50" height="50"></div>
           <div class="t1"><b>Plazas de movilidad</b></div>
           <div class="t2">+350</div>
           <div class="t1">Más de 350 plazas anuales de movilidad internacional.</div>
         </div>
         
         <div class="column">
           <div style="text-align: center">
           <img src="URL" class="middle" width="50" height="50"></div>
           <div class="t1"><b>Países</b></div>
           <div class="t2">37</div>
           <div class="t1">37 países con más de 120 universidades colaboradoras. </div>
         </div>
         
         <div class="column">
           <div style="text-align: center">
           <img src="URL" class="middle" width="50" height="50"></div>
           <div class="t1"><b>Dobles titulaciones</b></div>
           <div class="t2">26</div>
           <div class="t1">Posibilidad de obtener dobles titulaciones en 26 universidades.</div>
         </div>
         
         <div class="column">
         <div style="text-align: center">
         <img src="URL" class="middle" width="35" height="40"></div>
           <div class="t1"><b>Porcentaje</b></div>
           <div class="t2">+80%</div>
           <div class="t1">Más del 80% de los alumnos se van a su primera opción.</div>
         </div>
           
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

La idea es que aparezcan en 1 sola fila con 4 columnas, pero cuando lo incluyo en mi web me aparecen en 2 filas y 2 columnas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacer para que aparezca correctamente? He probado el código en páginas externas y me aparece así, que es como lo quiero, pero no logro que en mi web salga igual.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué tengo que hacer para que me salga como en la foto superior? ¿Tiene algo que ver con el CSS o con el tamaño del texto?
No sé cómo modificarlo. No me deja modificar el width ni el padding de las preguntas, ¿puede ser un problema de espacio?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' trato siempre de evitar referencias a `w3schools`. Están bien posicionados en Google, pero es un sitio plagado de malas prácticas y código no actualizado. El asunto fue discutido [en Meta (en inglés)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280478/5587982) y hay algunas buenas respuestas al respecto. Es mejor referir al sitio oficial de cada lenguaje-framework-biblioteca.

Comment: Si en páginas externas te funciona (se trata de un escenario limpio) y en la tuya no (no se trata de un escenario limpio) es que tienes que tener alguna regla CSS que esté afectando a tus elementos y que tienes en tu página pero no has subido aquí. Usa el inspeccionador de elementos de las herramientas de desarrollador de tu navegador (botón derecho del ratón y luego Inspeccionar) para ver que reglas están afectando a tus elementos `.column` y tendrás la respuesta a tu pregunta.

Comment: Interesante, @A.Cedano. Sé de la mala fama, si bien esa guía en concreto me resultó muy útil y creo que está bien curada. ¿Recomiendas alguna otra? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/ es la referencia oficial pero me parece más difícil de seguir

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Para CSS, aparte de la documentación oficial, hay buenos tutoriales en [CodePen](https://codepen.io) y en [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com), pero habría que buscarlos por temas específicos. Decidirse por una biblioteca como Bootstrap, a mi juicio, implicaría revisar el [Overview completo](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/overview/) para ver las posibilidades que da, cómo se hacen las cosas y ya para temas concretos puedes ver tutoriales en los sitios más arriba indicados o en otros.

Comment: @A.Cedano qué bueno. Acabo pues de sugerir su inclusión [en la wiki de \[css\]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/221856) (donde hay varias referencias a W3schools, por cierto, además de demasiados enlaces).

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' claro, es que como `w3schools` está bien posicionada en Google y tiene algo bueno que son los `Try It`, mucha gente se engancha y he visto varios usuarios con experiencia que recomiendan enlaces a esa página. Yo leí ya hace tiempo comentarios negativos sobre la calidad del código y luego he visto pésimas prácticas en algunos ejemplos de código PHP que confirmaron lo que se decía en esos comentarios. Por eso en las respuestas o comentarios siempre refiero a los sitios oficiales o a ejemplos concretos de páginas que garanticen buenas prácticas.

Comment: Fantástico, elimino pues mi primer mi comentario para no contribuir a promocionar esos enlaces. Gracias por toda la información

Answer (score 2):

A priori sustituiría en el CSS el `float: left` de la clase `column` por un `display: inline-block`, y cambiaría el `width: 25%` por un `width: 24%`.
Habría que bajar el ancho de 25% a 24% (o menor) porque al haber 4 columnas suman el 100% del espacio de la view, después hay que sumar el ancho del padding, que por columna son 10px. En total en la fila estás ocupando un 100% + 40px, por eso se desplazan las columnas a otra fila.

Hay formas mucho más elegantes con el `display: flex`:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ pero tal vez te venga bien hacer solo estos pequeños cambios.

```
.column {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 24%;
        padding: 5px;
      }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ya lo he solucionado